# Best reference for JavaFX CSS properties & selectors

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to learn JavaFX 2, but I've been stumbling a lot trying to style my application.  I've found [this document](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) which tries to document controls and the css properties that apply to them.  I can't tell if it's incomplete, if I should be using some unknown selectors or JavaFX's CSS support just isn't powerful enough for my needs.

Here are a couple of examples:

- How would I change the background color for the area behind a TabPane without coloring every other child component (is there a selector for that, or perhaps a property?)
- How would I change the color of non-selected tabs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

This uses an ID selector as shown in the "Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS" document. You could also leave off the "#MyTabPane" selector and have it apply to all TabPane's. (It looks like the .tab and .tab-content-area selectors are not discussed in the reference guide. I went to the "caspian.css" file contained in jfxrt.jar file to find them.)

TabExample.css

```
#MyTabPane .tab {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
#MyTabPane .tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

#MyTabPane .tab-content-area {
    -fx-background-color: cyan;
}

#MyTabPane .tab *.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

TabPaneEx.java

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        pane.setId(("MyTabPane"));
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("ONE");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("TWO");
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("THREE");
        pane.getTabs().addAll(tab1,tab2,tab3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("tabpaneex/TabExample.css").toString());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (in addition to .tab-header-background, which I also found in caspian.css).  It's a shame there isn't a more complete reference document, but I suppose that will come with time.

Comment: Great answer. For simplicity- is there a way to access the tab parts from from java.´? I'm thinking something along the lines of tabPane.getTabContent.setStyle()?

Answer (score 4):

[JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

[Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)

Comment: Neither of these documents seems to have solutions for these problem. Can I assume JavaFX's CSS isn't powerful enough for my needs?  If so, do I need to create a custom skin?  Without access to Oracle's original skins (in the com.sun package), I imagine that would be a lot of work.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want, but this should be similar.

Comment: Note the instruction in the second document to extract the default CSS file from the JavaFX Jar: 
`jar -xf jfxrt.jar com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css`

Comment: Oracles documentation of the CSS is essentially bloated garbage, with poor organization and categorization. They could do better.